# Layout and query Data for cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm new to noSQL and i want to use Azure CosmosDB. I'm working through a design with both embedded and reference data. for context, the data is test run results and projects. I have a `project` document to house meta data, and then a `testresult` document that houses the project name and project id, and then embeds all the data produced from running the test.

mockup testresult document

```
{
    "projectid": "770c934f-e59a-43ab-b5a0-4667f29ec16c",
    "projectname": "Lost Crypt Sample",
    "testsuite":{
      "commitid": "00000000",
      "starttime": "2023-08-08 20:37:08Z",
      "endtime": "2023-08-08 20:37:46Z",
      "duration": "37.306924",
      "passed": 3,
      "failed": 2,
      "failedtests": [
        {
            "testname": "MovementTest.MainScene_CharacterDoesNotFallIntoTextures",
            "duration": "12.495074",
            "message": "Character escaped the map and fell into textures! :("
        },
        {
            "testname": "MovementTest.MainScene_CharacterReachesWand",
            "duration": "25.0",
            "message": "Character Failed to reach the wand in time"
        }
      ],
    },
    "id": "23e9ba95-aba1-4d79-b5a1-32463d990ab9"
}
```

mockup project document

```
    "projectid": "770c934f-e59a-43ab-b5a0-4667f29ec16c",
    "projectname": "Lost Crypt Sample",
    "id": "0b4fe657-b110-42cb-af35-62f4e9c9ba2b",
    "owner":{
        "id":"123456",
        "name":"ownerName"
    }
```

what i'm need help with is writing a query where i can get a list of all the project names, and then the latest run based on starttime

i tried to follow the MS docs but i'm having a hard time. my query

```
SELECT distinct
        r.projectname
        , r.projectid
        , t.testsuite
FROM r
join
t in r.testsuite
```

returns 0 results.

First am i structuring my data correctly? I was using multiple containers, but found out that was improper. How does/do my app/I distinguish between my project and my test result. documents. Just by my class and it'll populate what it can like other json encoded classes/data?

Comment: Does `select * from r` return anything?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it returns all the documents. r becomes the alias for the json document returned.

Comment: Maybe you need `t.starttime` instead of `t.testsuite` in your select?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid same result even if i don't use the results of the join, the presence remove all the results

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding a type or doctype field in each document. This allows you to easily filter documents based on their type.

For example:

```json
{
    "doctype": "project",
    "projectid": "...",
    ...
}
```

```json
{
    "doctype": "testresult",
    "projectid": "...",
    ...
}
```

In your current query, since testsuite is not an array (based on your mockup), the join is not required.  Below query will get you a latest test run for each project.

```sql
SELECT r.projectname, r.projectid, r.testsuite
FROM r
WHERE r.doctype = "testresult"
ORDER BY r.testsuite.starttime DESC
```

When you retrieve data from CosmosDB, you can deserialize the JSON into your application's classes or data structures.

If you want only the latest test run for each project, you might need to handle that in your application logic or use below

```sql
SELECT r.projectname, r.projectid, r.testsuite
FROM r
WHERE r.doctype = "testresult" AND r.testsuite.starttime IN (
    SELECT VALUE MAX(t.testsuite.starttime)
    FROM t
    WHERE t.doctype = "testresult" AND t.projectid = r.projectid
)
```

But the above is not a very good approach, especially if you have a large number of test results. It's essentially a nested loop where for each test result, it's checking the maximum starttime for that project.

I will recommend considering following if performance becomes an issue:

Materialized View: Store the latest test result for each project in a separate document or container and update it whenever a new test result is added.

Application Logic: Instead of trying to do everything in a single query, use application logic to determine the latest test result for each project.

Change Feed: Use CosmosDB's change feed to listen for new test results and update a "latest" pointer for each project as new results come in.

Comment: I like the materialized view option. though, i only anticipate one view to need see the latest. I am going to want, at some point going to want to page through all the test results though for each project, one project at a time. i'm not sure how far back i should hold onto the results.